# I dont see the sharepoint lists in the output of power query

Tags: sharepoint-2010, powerquery

I installed the power query add on in Excel and connected the SP site as a data source in excel-power query .After the connection is established , the sharepoint lists are not seen in the navigator pane .

My aim is to export the meta data of all the lists within the site in a single excel .

Problem - if there are 5 lists in the site , I see only 3 in the output of the power query . ( I am one of the owners of the sharepoint site )

Answer (score 1):

If you right click the root in the navigator, click edit, and go to the advanced editor / formula bar, you should see some code like:

```
= SharePoint.Tables("your.sharepoint.com", [ApiVersion = 15])
```

Change the `SharePoint.Tables` to `SharePoint.Contents`. Now there should be a Lists row you can drill into.